# Scheme - displaying a binary tree

Tags: tree, scheme

I'm totally beginning my Scheme career and for last few days I'm struggling with a problem in the code. My task is to write a function that displays a binary tree. That's what I've done so far:

```
(define (get-pair t) (list (list-ref t 0) (list-ref t 1)))
(define (get-left t) (cadr t))
(define (get-right t) (caddr t))
    (define (print-tree tree) 
      (if (not (null? tree))       
       (begin
          (print-tree (get-left tree))
          (display (get-pair tree))
          (print-tree (get-right tree))
        )
       )
    )
```

Unfortunately, due to rules of the functional programming I can't use 'list-ref' command (just like 'append', 'list tail', 'vector' and so on). I'm a little stuck and therefore I've got a question: is it possible to exchange this part of the code or should I start the whole function again?

Comment: How come you can use `cadr` but not `list-ref`? `list-ref` is a pure function too..? (and `(list-ref t 0)` == `(car t)`)

Comment: I've got no idea why cadr is allowed ;) Do you know how to replace (list-ref t 1) too? I would be very grateful :)

Comment: That's what `cadr` does. In general `list-ref` with any constant index can be replaced with an appropriate `c*r` or manually nested invocations of `car` and `cdr`. You can easily implement it yourself with those primitives (and the specification [gives an example implementation](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_424)).

Comment: How to you represent a binary tree? I might implement a binary tree like `(list root-val left-tree right-tree)` where `left-tree` and `right-tree` are binary trees respectively. but that does not seems to be what you're doing.

Comment: @Alaya: As a Scheme newbie I'm wondering, why not as `'(root-val left-tree . right-tree)`? Then the structure doesn't need to contain any `Null` element, becoming somewhat smaller. But maybe that's a dubious optimization?

Comment: According to [R5RS](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-2.html#%_toc_%_sec_6.3.2) boh car and list-ref are purely functional, as is append!

Comment: @ValentinHuber I don't believe `append!` is purely functional as it mutate a data structure. `append` is purely functional. That said, I can see a performance issue with `list-ref` and `append` on big lists. For example, if you append multiple items to the tail of a growing list, each call to append will take more time. While you could simply use cons to prepend an item to the beggining of a list and reverse it when done. This will be much more faster. `list-ref` suffer the same issue as it has to scan the whole list.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: Indeed, "append!" is not. However, the exclamation mark was not intended to be read as part of the function name, but as the character terminating the sentence. Performance-wise I think your remark is correct as well, but: 1. First make it run, then make it run fast... 2. As I interpret it the original question wasn't about performance, but about properites of some standard functions.